# Difference between 'now and then' and 'again and again'

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between these phrases?

> 1. now and then
> 2. again and again

Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Now and then](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/now+and+then) is used to describe something that happens **sometimes**.

With [*again and again*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/again+and+again), you emphasize that something happens **repeatedly**. An alternative would be *over and over again*.

They cannot be used interchangeably - in fact, they feel more like [antonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonym) (opposites of each other).

Answer (score 1):

'Now and then' implies that it happens occasionally *and at irregular intervals*.  'Again and again' implies that it's happening a lot.